# Why is R sticking on importing a feather?

Tags: r

I have an R script that when I run it on a loop then it sticks after a variable number of iterations. No error messages - just hangs.

By way of an MRE:

```
library(arrow)

## clear environment
rm(list=ls())

### read in models
x <- 1
while (x < 50)
{
  print(x)
  matches_for_prediction <- read_feather(<file_path>)
  x = x + 1
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

I wondered if it could be some kind of open file conflict but I've tried extending the sleep to no avail.

Full confession... I mostly use Python and don't understand much about R.

Comment: To make this more reproducible you could (1) specify the operating system, (2) R and arrow version and (3) provide code to create a feather file.

Comment: @sindri_baldur - thanks for the advice. OS is Win 10, R is 4.0.3 and arrow is 2.0.0. It's going to take me a while to figure out how to create the file but I'll give it a go

Comment: any file that reproduces the hanging should do. The simpler the better.

Comment: Ok so there's a bit of an issue. A simple feather works like clockwork. I realise this would immediately point a finger towards there being a specific issue with data in the feather but the loop does work for a few times before it hangs. The number of iterations can vary from hanging on the first one to hanging on the 7th. I should also add that a friend has tried this code/file combo on their Mac and no issues at all :-/

Comment: Just tried reading a csv with the same data and no issues at all. I guess that's a sticking plaster but the actual files can get really big so I really need to use feather if possible

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem and through a lot of digging I found this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11579
It describes that sometimes on windows there is a thread deadlock. Possible solutions described there are:

- Reducing the number of threads arrow is allowed to use through arrow::set_cpu_count()
- Turning of multithreading for arrow through options(arrow.use_threads = FALSE)
- Not compressing the files when writing through write_feather(..., compression = "uncompressed")

Answer (score 0):

As the code runs perfectly on small files, it could be a memory problem.

You could try the following, which will give:

1. the size of the file you're trying to read
2. the size of the new object in R
3. the total memory used by R (`memory.size()` only works on Windows)
4. perform a garbage collection so that unused objects are eliminated

```
x <- 1
while (x < 50) {
  print(paste('Reading file #',x,":",format(structure(file.size(path), class="object_size"),units='auto')))
  matches_for_prediction <- read_feather(path)
  print(paste('Object size',format(object.size(matches_for_prediction),'auto'),'- Total Memory used :',memory.size()))
  gc()
  x = x + 1
}

[1] "Reading file # 1 : 108.5 Mb"
[1] "Object size 669.9 Mb - Total Memory used : 1258.53"
...
```

The loop will only finish if it fits in memory!

Comment: Thanks for this :-) The feather I'm testing on is only a few lines long with a couple of hundred columns. Pretty sure this wouldn't cause memory issues after a couple of iterations?

Comment: It doesn't cost much to run the above code to be sure ;-)